# SocketIO with CPU Intensive NodeJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm building a Chess AI in NodeJS. In my code, I have an Express endpoint that looks like this

server.js

```js
import { getAIMove } from "./getAIMove"
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = require("socket.io")(server, { /* Options */ })

app.get("/getComputerMove", (req, res) => {
  // Generally takes more than 30 seconds to run the function
  const AIMove = getAIMove(req, io, req.body.socketID)
  res.send(AIMove)
})
```

getAIMove.js

```js
export const getAIMove = (req, io, socketID) => {
  io.to(socketID).emit("status", "one")
  io.to(socketID).emit("status", "two")

  for (let i = 0, i < /* */; i++) {
    // This emits the percent that is completely calculated by the server
    io.to(socketID).emit("status", ...) // many times in loops
  }
}
```

However, I ran into 2 issues.

1. Due to how CPU intensive the task is, the socket, for some reason, disconnected and the reconnects with a new ID the moment the minimax algorithm is done. How do I somehow extend the thread like in Java, so that the SocketIO connection can still remain even during the calculation of the CPU Intensive function?
2. The socket only emits once. I tested the client's `socket.on` listener in all possible ways and concluded that it is the fault of the server. Somehow, I am only getting the status "one" and not "two" from the server. Is there something in Socket.IO version 3 that isn't fixed or is newly implemented that I don't know about???

Comment: about issue 1: I recommend you to somehow split these two tasks in mulitple threads. You can do this by using Worker Threads or some worker npm package like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-farm

Comment: When I follow the docs and use worker-farm, somehow the methods of my defined classes are getting errors like `tile.isEmpty is not a function` when `tile.isEmpty` is definitely a function... Is it something to do with the fact that I have to use module.exports with the worker-farm module?

Comment: sorry I don't know the package in details. You could open a new thread about "worker-farms" and post your code there. It's hard to make any suggestions without knowing your code.